# Meaning of "wont" in a poem

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, poetry

I was translating this poem by Lord Byron:

> If, in the month of dark December,
>
> Leander, who was nightly **wont**
>
> (What maid will not the tale remember?)
>
> To cross thy stream, broad Hellespont!

Actually I have more questions regarding the syntax but I don't think it's allowed to ask multiple questions here. so here's my question:

The **wont** in this poem, what does it mean?

I thought it means **will not**... to cross thy stream, but it looks like an older usage.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: (In other words, look in a dictionary before asking here.)

Comment: sorry about that, i never thought this could be  in a dictionary

Comment: _Wont_ is an adjective, usually used as a predicate adjective with an infinitive complement, as in _He is wont to abuse his privileges._ As a predicate adjective, it requires an auxiliary _be_; it means, roughly, 'likely' or 'probable'. It's distantly related to _want_, but only distantly; however, the sense of doing something because one can, whether it's the right thing to do or not, is very strong. BTW, it's pronounced /wənt/, to rhyme with _bunt_

Comment: *Wont* certainly isn't pronounced /wənt/ in British English. It's /woʊnt/, like the contraction *won't*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wont" in this context refers to Leander's habit of going out during the night to cross the stream. Wont can mean accustomed to or in the habit of performing a task or be inclined to do something.

It's not like the word "won't" which you've already mentioned. Almost the same spelling, but completely different meaning.

Merriam-Webster offers an expanded definition: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wont

Comment: ah yes, i get the meaning lot more clearly now. thank you my good man.

Comment: For some reason, someone texting "wont" instead of "won't" feels less barbarous to me than a sign saying "potatoe's" over some potatoes. ;)

Answer (score -2):

It is not "won't", but an archaic form of "want"

Comment: This is not correct. The etymology of *wont* is from the Anglo-Saxon *won* meaning *to dwell* (OED).